# PHP ошибка расчета чисел float

Tags: php

объясните пожалуйста почему так и как можно обойти эту проблему:

```php
(-1 * (float)0) === 0) // false
```

*Рассчитываю сумму скидки на сайте, и вот такое произошло при скидке 100%*

Comment: `intval(-1 * (float)0) === 0 //  true`  слева флоат справа инт

Comment: или  же `(-1 * (float)0) === 0. // true`  === - проверяет на точное совпадение типов, а не только значений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как можно обойти эту проблему

так как по разные стороны сравнения типы данных разные вы можете избежать этого двумя способами
1 использовать неточный тип сравнения

```
(-1 * (float)0) == 0)
```

2 сравнивать одинаковые типы данных

```
(-1 * (float)0) === (float)0
```